# Make text visible above overlapping div

Tags: html, css

I have a design requirement where a div has to overlap another div, but the text within the inner div needs to be visible.

```
<div class='box1'>
  <div class='sendAbove'>
    This is a message I want to be visible in this div
  </div>
</div>

<div class='box2'>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: white;
  border: solid red 1px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.sendAbove {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sriv87/Lcoxrgpw/9/

Edit:
Updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sriv87/c8eh5fcs/

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Make the second box transparent? https://jsfiddle.net/2j60k9yu/

Comment: @sol No, Its a design requirement. I need the border to be overlapped, but not the text

Comment: Can you provide an image of the desired outcome.

Comment: @sol I updated the fiddle and expected image

Comment: Are you trying to make something like a talk bubble?

Comment: you are overcomplicating it ... and you lead us to something else, you need to be clear from the beginning that you need a particular shape instead of providing another problem

Comment: @TemaniAfif - am sorry I didn't make the connect to the speech bubble myself. Am designing this for a custom map placeholder.

Comment: i know but next time better be direct on what you need :) so you need to tell us what  your are trying to achieve instead of showing us a method where you want to force things in order to achieve somthing we don't know as we may guide you to better ways instead of helping fixing a complicated way

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Edited as per your updated requirement. Check this.

```css
.callout {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  width: 200px;
}

.callout:after,
.callout:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.callout:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.callout:before {
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left-color: #f00;
  border-width: 11px;
  margin-top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="callout">
  <p>Message here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope this is what you were looking for. Your question wasn't very clear.

Comment: I have updated the question. I cannot put the message separate from the box1 since I need a border. The text may be dynamic length and I still need a border for it.

Comment: Try this, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

With your current layout it wont work. Because the parent of `.sendAbove` is absolute positioned, its `html` will allways be part of its parent. Regardless you make it `absolute` or `relative`.

So to make this workable, you should put the `.sendAbove` outside `.box1`. Give them both the same position, height and width.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;  
}

.box1, .sendAbove {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  background: white;
  border: solid red 1px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.sendAbove {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class='box1'>
</div>

<div class='sendAbove'>
    This is a message I want to be visible in this div
  </div>

<div class='box2'>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the message is dynamic. The width and the height would vary for me to set the border. I have updated the question to give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the background color settings in .box2 and that will make text underneath visible. How visible will be decided by the 'a' in rgba, and runs from 0 to 1, ie, 0.1 is very transparent, 0.9 has virtually no transparency.

```
 .box2 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: 50px;
      **background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);**
      border: solid blue 1px;
      z-index: 4;
```

}